# external network for django Webpage

Tags: python, django

I have a project in Django and it is running on my local machine, I got to make the setting by putting: `Allowedhosts = ["*"]` and `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` This is enough so that I can access the page through another machine on the same network, but I would like to know a way to make access available through an external network, the question is, how do I do it ??

Comment: Impossible in django, you need to configure port forwarding on your router

Comment: @mousetail if I release port 100 for example, how do I get django to run on that port??

Comment: Simply replace the `8000` with whatever port you want to run on

Comment: @mousetail Thanks man, I was thinking along those lines but wasn't sure if that was it, thanks for your help and your time

Comment: @mousetail To configure the entire domain part is also externally right???

Comment: `0.0.0.0`. means "anything", so you will respond to connections no matter where they are destined, as long as they reach your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose your machine to the external network you are trying to access from through your router.

Be aware that with this code you will be exposing the 8000 port and everyone in that network could be able to access your site. To limit who can access, you can add the incoming IP to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'EXTERNAL_IP']
```

Check reference at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts